# How to extract row from file and put it into my object Article(int Code, string Name, string Amount)

Tags: c#, dictionary

Initialize new object

```
Article article = new Article();
```

New dictionary:

```
Dictionary<int, Article> articles = new Dictionary<int, Article>();
```

Read the file and display it line by line.

```
System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"D:\Posao\Zadatak 3\Zadatak3\Zadatak3\Dokumenti\artikli.txt");
while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    var row = line.Split('|').ToString();
}
```

My class Article:

```
public class Article
{
   private int Code { get; set; }
   private string Name { get; set; }
   private string Amount { get; set; }
}
```

My file looks like this:

```
343534|Food|Piece

657765|Milk|Liter
...
```

In each row i got three parameters `(10934, 'food', 'piece'` and same for another row with different values)

And those row's properties are properties from my class Article

So the question is how can I put those values into my object after I get them from row?

Comment: Do you know how to create an `Article` object from `row`? What is your actual problem there? So far, your code looks good, you just need to use the values of `row` and construct the article, and then add the created article to the dictionary. Btw. you should create a new article *inside the loop*. You might also want to look into CSV parsing with C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a working code sample based on yours

```
 class Program
{

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Dictionary<int, Article> articles = new Dictionary<int, Article>();
         using (System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(@"\artikli.txt"))
        {
            string line = "";
            int lineCounter = 1;
            while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (line.Contains("|"))
                {
                    var row = line.Split('|');
                    articles.Add(lineCounter++, new Article() { Code = int.Parse(row[0]), Name = row[1], Amount = row[2] });
                }
            }
            file.Close();
        }
    }

    public class Article
    {
        public int Code { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Amount { get; set; }
        public Article() { }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The way your `Article` class is at the moment, there is no way to set or access any of the properties from the class: they are all `private`.

If you want to define a readonly property, you will have to make it `public` with only a `get` method defined. You can still assign values to the properties from a constructor of the class. You should define a one taking the three pieces of information as parameters and assign the properties from there.

Please note that your class is actually a good candidate for being converted to a `struct`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code as it is has currently two issues:

---

The first one is, that your properties in your class `Article` are private. So you are not allow to access them out of your class scope.

For more information you can take a look at 
[C# - Access Modifiers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/access-modifiers) and [C# - Accessibility Levels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/accessibility-levels).

So at first you should make the properties__public__ to be able to get and set the values. If you only want to allow the usage of the getter you should at least add a non-parameterless constructor like:

```
public Article(int code, string name, string amount) 
{
     // assign parameter here ...
}
```

and set your properties to something like

```
public string Name { get; private set}
```

---

The second one is your line:

```
var row = line.Split('|').ToString();
```

Here you are creating just a string containing `"System.String[]"`. `var` in this current code represents the type of string, but what you need is a string array.

So when you remove the `ToString()` your `row` variable will now look like

```
string[3] { "343534", "Food", "Piece" }`.
```

---

Now you just can create a new `Article` like:

```
 string line = "343534|Food|Piece";
 string[] row = line.Split('|'); // string[3] { "343534", "Food", "Piece" }

 Article  article = new Article();
 article.Code = Convert.ToInt32(row[0]);
 article.Name = row[1];
 article.Amount = row[2];
```

or in a shorter way using [Object Initializer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers):

```
 Article  article = new Article 
 { 
     Code = Convert.ToInt32(row[0]),
     Name = row[1],
     Amount = row[2]
 }
```